# How to insert a structure into a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, structure, handler

I am writing a matlab function as :

```
function [resultNorm]= explorEffort (n, loop, step)
...
Somelines
...
M=bench(a,b).Y ;
end
```

but it seems that the matlab compiler doesn't let me use a structure in the function, the error is:

```
Error: File: explorEffort.m Line: 20 Column: 15
Functions cannot be indexed using {} or . indexing.
```

P.S: the bench definition

```
bench = 

24x5 struct array with fields:

application
dataset
mica
micaNorm
DB
Y
```

Could anyone mention how am I gonna be able to fix that?

Comment: How is `bench` defined?

Comment: @herohuyongtao, i figured it out buddy, tnx anyways ;) I think I should have defined it as global or passing it by the function.

Comment: @Amir In that case, you should post your answer. = )

Comment: @Phonon, Ok, doing that!

Answer (score 0):

Method-1

There is a possibility to define the structure (namely here, `bench`) as global outside the file and just call `global bench;` right before the first appearance of the `bench`.

Method-2

the safer choice could be passing the structure among the input argument of the function as :

```
function [resultNorm]= explorEffort (n, loop, step, `bench`)
```

in this case no need to prior unnecessary globalization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue was that "bench" is a MATLAB builtin(depending on your version of matlab).
You can try renaming your variable in the future.

you can run :
X=bench; or help bench

I run into similar issue before.